# How to fprintf properly on my character struct array that contains Hex byte characters

Tags: c, formatting, printf

Here's my problem, I have a byte struct that looks like these:

```
struct machinecode{
    char byte1[2];
    char byte2[2];
    char byte3[2];
    char byte4[2];
    char byte5[2];
    char byte6[2];
    char byte7[2];
    char byte8[2];
    char byte9[2];
};
struct machinecode WRITEME[500];
```

now, these collection of 2byte chars or strings are formatted in hex bytes that looks like these for example:

byte1 = "01"

byte2 = "C0"

char bytes are assigned like these:

```
...
char * returner
...
strncpy(WRITEME[index].byte1, "00", 2);
strncpy(WRITEME[index].byte2, returner, 2);
```

my printing code looks like these:

```
while(counter < max){
...
    else if(prog_counter[counter2] == 2){
            fprintf(w, ???, WRITEME[counter].byte1);
            fprintf(w, ???, WRITEME[counter].byte2);
    }
...
}
```

Now I wanted this to print string as hex bytes, what kind of formatting(???) do I need to use for fprintf? or do I need to convert this hex byte string first to int before fprinting them?

I tried "%x", "%X" but they doesn't work.

EDIT:

I would like to add that I'm making a .com executable file, so I need to print them as hex bytes.

Comment: how did you assign values bytes[] arrays? "01" is string?

Comment: They are assigned character strings. So in ascii: "48 49"

Comment: Can you show the actual assignment to `WRITEME[counter].byte1`?  There are many ways that would be wrong, and fewer that would be right.

Comment: Here's an example:

char * returner;

strncpy(WRITEME[index].byte1, "00", 2);

strncpy(WRITEME[index].byte2, returner, 2);

Comment: Consider an array: `char byte[9][2];` instead of 9 struct members. Remember array indexes start at `0`.

Comment: Using `strncpy(..., 2);` is one of the correct ways of assigning to the structure members.  We needed to check for your safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Revised answer

You say *"I'm making a `.COM` executable file so I need to print them as hex bytes"*.  The immediate response is then "Why on earth are you converting the values into a pair of bytes in the first place?"  You'll have to convert them back to a single byte and then write that byte using the `%c` notation.  One way, probably not the best way, to do that is:

```
static const char hexits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
static inline int byte_from_hex(const char *hex)
{
    assert(isxdigit(hex[0]) && isxdigit(hex[1]));
    int b1 = strchr(hexits, toupper((unsigned char)hex[0])) - hexits;
    int b2 = strchr(hexits, toupper((unsigned char)hex[1])) - hexits;
    return b1 * 16 + b2;
}

fprintf(w, "%c", byte_from_hex(WRITEME[counter].byte1);
```

But it would be far simpler not to convert to a string in the first place.

#### Original answer

Because your data is not null terminated, you need to use a length in the conversion specifications, as specified in the [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) manual page:

```
%.2s
```

This means print at most 2 characters from the character array.

```
fprintf(w, "%.2s", WRITEME[counter].byte1);
```

This assumes you did something like:

```
WRITEME[counter].byte1[0] = '0';
WRITEME[counter].byte2[1] = '1';
```

or:

```
memmove(WRITEME[counter].byte1, "01", sizeof(WRITEME[counter].byte1);
```

or (as the comments showed you did):

```
strncpy(WRITEME[counter].byte1, "01", 2);  // or sizeof(WRITEME[counter].byte1)
```

and that you *did not* do something like:

```
sprintf(WRITEME[counter].byte1, "%2X", byte_value);
```

and that you *did not* do something like:

```
strcpy(WRITEME[counter].byte1, "01");
```

Comment: I guess I need to make a function that will convert hex to int since c language doesn't have a direct formatting for printing that will convert hex to int or char

Comment: You could almost use `sscanf()` because it is designed for converting strings to other types, but it requires null-terminated strings as input and you don't have a null terminated string.  You could try `int byte_val; sscanf(WRITEME[counter].byte1, "%2x", &byte_val); fprintf(w, "%c", byte_val);` and I think it should be safe because you've constrained it to read at most 2 characters and there are no leading blanks to worry about. But it is treading on thin ice.  Are you sure you can't use `0x01` in place of `"01"`?

Comment: I could use 0x<hex> format, but maybe edit a lot of strncpy's and change the struct format. But I'll try the sscanf function that you have suggested before doing that. 

To answer your question: "Why on earth are you converting the values into a pair of bytes in the first place?" 

I chose to display a hex byte string format so I can easily debug and compare if my assembler is spewing correct opcodes or not. I'm actually playing with binary format but just converting it to hex byte here in the printing process cause I shortsightedly assumed that C print can convert hex to bytes directly

Comment: I just tried the sscanf and fprintf method and it looks like it works, but the expoted .com file is getting random "0d" bytes in it. I can't trace the bug for it, do you know what is causing fprint to write "0d" bytes or carriage return? I've look hard enough and I can't find what's causing it

Comment: Did you open the file for writing as a binary file?  If you opened it as a text file, you'd find that any time you wrote a 0x0A (^J, newlinw) byte, the system would write a 0x0D (^M, carriage return) byte before hand.  Otherwise, there's no obvious reason for the additional bytes...and I see from your 'answer' that it was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fix this.

First I used [Jonathan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967151/1862452) of using sscanf and printf.

Then I encountered a weird bug that puts random "0d" on my file.

The solution was to open and write the file in binary mode.

```
w = fopen( filename , "wb" );
```

Hope this helps other users in the future